# Cron schedule in quartz to fire every week from a specific date for one year

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a scenario, where I need to schedule a job using quartz which triggers every week from the date specified by the user and this should continue for exactly one year.
After going through Cron Schedule examples, I think below cron expression might help me:
eg. If date specified is 31-10-2015, then the expression would be:

" 0 30 20 31/7 10-10 ? 2015-2016 "  which means starting from 31 Oct 3015, trigger after every 7 days for 1 year, ie. till 31 Oct 2016.

Please let me know if there are any issues with this expression.
Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

Your cron-expression is not valid as per [CronMaker.Com](http://www.cronmaker.com). Looking at your cron expression, I have following things:

1. Your job fires at 8:30PM
2. It is weekly job running all 7 days of week
3. It ends in 2016

Here is the correct cron expression :

```
0 30 20 ? * 2,3,4,5,6,7,1 2015,2016 //Runs all days of week
```

To expire it on 31st Oct in 2016, you will have to provide Ending time while creating this job.

**Update:**

If you want to fire this job on a particular day of week, it will be something as below:

```
0 30 20 ? * MON 2015,2016 //Runs every week on monday
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But I don't need to fire it daily.It should be once in a week starting from a particular date for one year.

Comment: @user3259903 Once in a week, but on which day?

Comment: @user3259903 Modified my answer to suit what you need.

Answer (score 0):

even i had same requirement, i implemented as below

we can run for every seven days from the start date, seven days when converted to hours, value is 168

```
JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
    jobDataMap.put("json", json);
    String startDateStr = "2017-06-21 00:00:00.0";
    Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr);
    String endDateStr = "2018-06-21 00:00:00.0";
    Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr);
    JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class).withIdentity(name, "group1").build();
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
             .startAt(startDate)
            .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(168).repeatForever())
            .endAt(endDate)
            .usingJobData(jobDataMap)
            .build();
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.start();
```

hope it helps!!